# problem in deleting a node in algorithm to reverse a linked list c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, linked-list, nodes, reverse

I'm solving problems in algorithms and I have to reverse a forward linked list.
Here is my code:
For a node:

```
struct Node{
    int value;
    Node* next;
};
```

For reversing, here is the algorithm I made:

```
Node* reverse(Node* head){
    Node* node = head->next;
    Node* sentry = new Node;
    sentry->next = head;
    while(node != nullptr){
        head->next = node->next;
        node->next = sentry->next;
        sentry->next = node;
        node = head->next;
    }
    return sentry;
}
```

Here is a print function to test:

```
void print(Node* head){
    Node* node = head->next;
    while(node != nullptr){
        std::cout << node->value << '-';
        node = node->next;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the reversed list has as last node the head, so when I try to do: `delete head;` before `return sentry;` to delete that node I get Core Dump error. I know that I can just search in internet a method to reverse the list, but I want to understand why this happens, why can't I just delete the head node.

Edit: here's is the code deleting the head:

```
Node* reverse(Node* head){
    Node* node = head->next;
    Node* sentry = new Node;
    sentry->next = head;
    while(node != nullptr){
        head->next = node->next;
        node->next = sentry->next;
        sentry->next = node;
        node = head->next;
    }
    delete head; // head = nullptr; also doesn't work.
    return sentry;
}
```

Here is a main function to test:

```
int main(){
    Node* node5 = new Node{5,nullptr};
    Node* node4 = new Node{4,node5};
    Node* node3 = new Node{3,node4};
    Node* node2 = new Node{2,node3};
    Node* node1 = new Node{1,node2};
    Node* head = new Node;
    head->next = node1;
    head->value;
    print(reverse(head));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When reversing a list there is usually no need to allocate more nodes, so keep an eye on `Node* sentry = new Node;`

Comment: Recommendation draw pictures of the list to help visualize the problem. Draw a picture of the list at every step you need to perform in order to reverse a small, say 3 node, list. Then following the instructions in your code try to draw the same list. If you can't, you'll quickly see where the two diverge.

Comment: It was my attempt to a solution, creating a node before head, and append all the elements that came after head to the node that I created, then simply just delete the head node, it reverses the list well, but I want to understand why I'm unable to delete the head node.

Comment: @user4581301 also, when I do head = nullptr, it just ignore it, and keeps printing the head node, so I can't delete it or make it null. The question is more related to the programming language than the algorithm itself, it is "why I can't do something that it looks like I can".

Comment: If the problem you are encountering is when deleting `head`, can you include the code when you actually call `delete head` and where you call reverse?

Comment: Do you reserve the `head` node for a special purpose? I see you don't print it...

Comment: Have a chat with [your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) about the circumstances under which it makes sense to delete an item when reversing the order of the items.

Comment: It's unsafe to delete a pointer that was passed to a function, since the function has no way of knowing how that pointer was created.

Comment: @trincot yes, I put my main function in the question, where I have the head empty to avoid checking for empty lists.

Comment: @44stonelions So, no way to delete a pointer that I passed?

Comment: You can, but you can only `delete` pointers that are created with `new`, the interface of the function doesn't guarantee this. So you could pass in a stack allocated pointer which ends up getting deleted. (Although your head node is created with new so that isn't the problem here, but it is an unsafe design)

Comment: The head of the list should always be the first element in the list. It's not special.

Comment: That's a nonstandard way to work with lists. Just skip that dummy node and let head be the first node. If the list is empty, then this will correspond to the head pointer being nullptr. There is no need for this extra node.

Comment: There are good uses of special purpose head and tail nodes, and I think based on the naming of the `sentry` variable that this could be what the asker is trying to implement, but we need a [mre] and a solid explanation of the design to fully understand the asker's goals.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at your code:

```
void print(Node* head){
    Node* node = head->next;
    while(node != nullptr){
        std::cout << node->value << '-';
        node = node->next;
    }
}
```

This code will never print the head. Slightly better code would be:

```
void print(Node* head) {
    for (Node * node = head; node != nullptr; node = node->next) {
        std::cout << node->value << '-';
    }
}
```

Now, from your code in `main` it looks like you don't expect to print the head -- you're using it as a pointer. That would be odd. You basically have an extra, empty node just hanging out. So your `main` could do this:

```
int main(){
    Node* node5 = new Node{5,nullptr};
    Node* node4 = new Node{4,node5};
    Node* node3 = new Node{3,node4};
    Node* node2 = new Node{2,node3};
    Node* head = new Node{1,node2};

    std::cout << "Original version: ";
    print(head);
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "Reversed version: ";
    print(reverse(head));
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Finally, your reverse method is flat out broken. You shouldn't have to allocate anything.

Linked lists and other forms of linked structures (like trees) can be very confusing. At this stage in your learning, drawing pictures REALLY helps. I did so for years and years, and I still do when it gets complicated.

```
Note * reverse(Node *head) {
    Node * prev = nullptr;

    while (head != nullptr) {
        Node * nextNode = head->next;

        head->next = prev;
        prev = head;
        head = nextNode;
    }

    return prev;
}
```

There's probably a more elegant way to do this, but I don't want to think that hard :-)

Think about what this does. It keeps track of the previous node. The first time through the loop, there is no previous node. After that, the previous node is the old head, then old head->next, et cetera.

At each node, it sets the next pointer to this previous node. So head->next becomes nullptr (it's the new end of the list). Old Head->next->next comes old head, et cetera.

I haven't tested this code.

This is my final copy with a compile and output:

```
^ make Foo && Foo
g++     Foo.cpp   -o Foo
Original: 1 : 2 : 3 : 4 : 5 : 

Reversed: 5 : 4 : 3 : 2 : 1 : 

^ cat Foo.cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Node{
    Node (int v): value(v) {}

    int value = 0;
    Node* next = nullptr;
};

void print(Node* head);
Node * reverse(Node* head);

int main() {
    // This part is gross, but I was in a hurry
    Node * head = new Node(1);
    head->next = new Node(2);
    head->next->next = new Node(3);
    head->next->next->next = new Node(4);
    head->next->next->next->next = new Node(5);

    std::cout << "Original: ";
    print(head);
    std::cout << "\n\nReversed: ";
    print(reverse(head));
    std::cout << "\n";
}

void print(Node* head) {
    for (Node * node = head; node != nullptr; node = node->next) {
        std::cout << node->value << " : ";
    }
}

Node * reverse(Node *head) {
    Node * prev = nullptr;

    while (head != nullptr) {
        Node * nextNode = head->next;

        head->next = prev;
        prev = head;
        head = nextNode;
    }

    return prev;
}
```